# Anaconda : change environnement error - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, anaconda, macos-sierra

it's really the first that I need to create second python environment and I need your help!

I have created a new environment with anaconda (on Mac OS 10.12.4). But I can't witch from my basic root environment to the new one.

I am using this code from the documentation :

```
source activate <myenvname>

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/llvmlite-0.17.0-py3.5.egg-info/PKG-INFO'
```

Even I am using 'sudo', it doesn't work...

With the anaconda navigator, I tried to launch the second environment with 'open terminal' but I have the same error.

[root environment and the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWXqM.png)

I didn't found a clear answer in internet... :)

All the best,

Comment: It looks that your 'conda env' is not created properly as not many packages are shown in Anaconda Navigator. You try to create another one and try to switch to it again. Apart from using Navigator, you can use command `conda create --name yourenv python=3.5 anaconda` to create a new `conda env`.

Comment: Thanks you to take a moment to reply! but it still doesn't work.                     sudo: source: command not found

Comment: I didn't encountered any issue in my Mac Book with same Mac OS as your one. `source` command works perfectly.  Alternatively, have you tried to launch `Jupyter` from `Anaconda Navigator`?  When create a new notebook, `Jupyter` allows to set `env` if it works properly.

Comment: it's weird. I can run anaconda navigator from the terminal but from the launchpad it's impossible. from the navigator, I can't launch Jupyter.     PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Comment: I tried to launch Jupiter from terminal with "sudo jupyter-notebook" but I have "Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.".

Comment: Have you enabled `root` user? If not, see [this](https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT204012) and have a try again.  It seems that something messed up. You may need to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it again to clean up.

Comment: Now I have activated root user but in terminal when I type 'source activate <myenv>' it says : -sh: activate: No such file or directory. And I ask 'conda info -e', and it says : '-sh: conda: command not found'

Comment: the shame I have successfully installed opencv last evening

Comment: Suggest to reinstall Anaconda if you want to have a try.

Comment: hi, I did it and everything work correctly! but I did it with command line installer, not with graphical installer. but now, I have installed opencv with condo and I can't switch between my environments... root from the new one. The same error 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'. maybe this error comes from the bash_profile ? my new environment is set up with python 3.6 and the root with python 3.5. I can type 'source deactivate <myenv>' but impossible to activate it. Opencv is installed on the root

Comment: If OpenCV is installed in `conda root`, then you can test it if it works in a terminal (1) type python, (2) `>>>import cv2` and (3)`>>>print cv2.__version__`. For changing `conda env`, have you tried `sudo source activate <yourenv>`? The permission error is on MacOS shell level.

Comment: open cv works correctly. I did it with sudo but I have 'sudo: source: command not found' again

Comment: What's the whole `sudo` command you typed in? Can you take a screenshot with the error message, then EDIT your question to include the image?

Comment: Done! you have the all terminal window in the question. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source` is a shell built-in command, it can't be executed without the shell.
`sudo` doesn't run the shell by default. To explicitly execute the shell, use the `-s` option.

```
sudo -s source activate orangecolors
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I added one image with this line but it doesn't work properly. Still python 3.5 and not 3.6. it's weird. My MacBook Pro is haunted

Comment: You may try these two commands. 1) 'sudo su' then 2) 'source activate orangecolors'. Supposed it's easy to get it work.

Comment: Great! Please spend time to read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).